# intuition for finding examples of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find two linear transformation $U,T: F^2 \to F^2 $ such that $UT = \mathbf{0} $ but $TU \neq \mathbf{0}$.

I know the answer to this, which is $T(x,y)=(x,0); U(x,y)=(y,y)$. What's the intuition to come up with examples like those? Is there another pair of answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v$ and $w$ be linearly independent vectors of $\mathbb R^2$ and consider the linear map $U\colon\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R^2$ such that $U(v)=w$ and $U(w)=0$. If $T\colon\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R^2$ is such that $T$ maps every element of $\mathbb R^2$ into a multiple of $w$, then $U\circ T=0$. You also want to have $T\circ U\neq0$. So, take $T$ such that $T(v)=T(w)=w$, for instance.